# JavaScript clone form element issue with index numbering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which I want to record an exercise set, then add new sets as required. This part is working well, but if you delete a set other than the last, it throws out the set numbering.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <tbody class="tbodyClone">
        <tr id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
            <td><h4 name="set" class="heading-reference">Set 1</h4>
              <select id="style" class="form-control">
                <option>Pull ups</option>
                <option>Push ups</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="weight" class="form-control">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="reps" class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                                                                   </select></td>
            <td>
                <button id="btnAdd_0" name="btnAdd_0" type="button" class="clone btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                <button id="btnDel_0" name="btnDel_0" type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;

var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
    $('.remove').hide();
} else {
    $('.remove').show();
}
function clone() {
     cloneIndex++;

    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .appendTo(".tbodyClone")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
        .find(".heading-reference").text('Set ' + cloneIndex)
        .on('click', 'clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'remove', remove);


    //delete
    console.log("Total lines => " + $(".clonedInput").length);

    if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }

}
function remove() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

    cloneIndex--;

    if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }

}
$(document).on("click", ".clone", clone);
$(document).on("click", ".remove", remove);
```

Is there any way I can keep the set numbers in sequential order even if a set gets deleted?

Comment: Make it simpler. I use {{index_}} in html class/id and replace {{index}} with index value (reindex) every time event performs.

Comment: another option is to use the jQuery array of `$(".clonedInput")` as your identifiers (instead of element IDs), which will automatically shift as you remove or add elements. You can use `$(".clonedInput").get(index)` to get a specific element, and observe `$(".clonedInput").length` to see the total amount of elements. `$(".clonedInput").get(0)` is the first element, `$(".clonedInput").get($(".clonedInput").length-1)` is the last one.

Comment: @WardD.S. please excuse my ignorance, I'm still learning. Are you refering to this section of the script `//delete
    console.log("Total lines => " + $(".clonedInput").length);

    if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I definitely like simpler! are you suggesting I change `<div class="form-group">` to `<div class="index_group">` ?

Comment: No add "clonedInput1" to "clonedInput_{{index}}" and replace {{index}} with index value.Reset index at every change.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to incorporate this into your existing code would be to refactor the IDs of all following rows after removing one.

```
function remove() {
  var toRemove = $(this).closest(".clonedInput");
  // which ID are we removing?
  var removedId = parseInt(toRemove.attr('id').replace("clonedInput",""));

  // .nextAll will take all following siblings, that match the selector.
  // this avoids reassigning IDs to entries in front of the removed one...
  // ...since they don't change anyway
  toRemove.nextAll('.clonedInput').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', "clonedInput"+(removedId)).find(".heading-reference").text('Set ' + removedId)
    removedId++;
  });
  toRemove.remove();

  cloneIndex--;

  if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
      $('.remove').hide();
  } else {
      $('.remove').show();
  }
}
```

Didn't test this code, so let me know if anything goes wrong.

Comment: i think this.id = "clonedInput"+(removedId++); should be this.id = "clonedInput"+ ++removedId; Or it'll assign the same id for the first element.

Comment: We want to re-use the id of the element that gets removed, so first append and then increase the counter.

Comment: @WardD.S. I can't make this code work. I'm replacing the `function remove( )` section of my script, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.index()` gets you the index of the matched elements.

Please note that you do not want id's on elements within the clones without altering them -- an `id` should be unique over the entire page. I have not removed all in the snippet.

```js
function fixVisibility()
{
    // or just do this in css
    if ($(".clonedInput").length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }
}

function fixIndices()
{
  // if you delete an item on top, the indices should be fixed.
  $('.clonedInput').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    var cloneIndex = tr.index() + 1;
    tr.removeAttr('id')
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
        .find(".heading-reference").text('Set ' + cloneIndex).end();
  });
}

function clone()
{
    var tr = $(this).closest(".clonedInput");
    var cloneIndex = tr.index() + 2;
  
    tr.clone().removeAttr('id')
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
        .find(".heading-reference").text('Set ' + cloneIndex).end()
        .appendTo('.tbodyClone');
  
    fixVisibility();


    //delete
    console.log("Total lines => " + $(".clonedInput").length);

}

function remove() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

    fixVisibility();
    fixIndices();
}

fixVisibility();
$(document).on("click", ".clone", clone);
$(document).on("click", ".remove", remove);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-group">
    <tbody class="tbodyClone">
        <tr id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
            <td><h4 name="set" class="heading-reference">Set 1</h4>
              <select id="style" class="form-control">
                <option>Pull ups</option>
                <option>Push ups</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="weight" class="form-control">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="reps" class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select></td>
            <td>
                <button class="clone btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                <button class="remove btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is pretty close but if you add a set between sets, it doesn't readjust the numbers.